# How to select the total sum of certain table fields based on other joined table conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have been working on an expense tracking system. I have three main tables: 'expenses', 'expense_reports', 'payments'.

I structured my database like this:

- 'expenses' belongs to one 'expense_reports'
- 'expense_reports' has many 'expenses'
- 'expense_reports' belongs to many 'payments'
- 'payments' belongs to many 'expense_reports'

I added a pivot table namely 'expense_report_payment' for 'expense_reports' and 'payments' tables to handle many-to-many relationships. 'expense_report_payment' table has the ff fields:

- id
- expense_report_id
- payment_id
- payment

This is my query to fetch the total sum of expenses and payments:

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(SUM(ex.`amount`), 0) AS total_expenses,
  IFNULL(SUM(erp.`payment`), 0) AS total_payment 
FROM
  `expenses` ex 
  JOIN `expense_reports` er 
    ON er.`id` = ex.`expense_report_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `expense_report_payment` erp 
    ON erp.`expense_report_id` = er.`id` 
  JOIN `payments` p 
    ON p.`id` = erp.`payment_id` 
    AND p.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
    AND p.`cancelled_at` IS NULL 
    AND p.`received_at` IS NOT NULL 
WHERE ex.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
  AND er.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
  AND er.`rejected_at` IS NULL 
  AND er.`cancelled_at` IS NULL
```

I get the total amount of values if there is a received payment (total_expenses = 100; total_payment = 100). However, if the payment has not been received yet, the total amount of both expenses and payments are zero.

Comment: You must use LEFT JOIN after the first one in joining chain. `payments` is joined to `expense_report_payment`, so it is in leftjoined chain and must be LEFT joined too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help. I managed to resolve the issue by JOINING 'expense_report_payment' and 'payments' table inside a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(SUM(ex.`amount`), 0) AS total_expenses,
  IFNULL(SUM(erp.payment), 0) AS total_payment
FROM
  `expenses` ex 
  JOIN `expense_reports` er 
    ON er.`id` = ex.`expense_report_id` 
    AND er.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
    AND er.`rejected_at` IS NULL 
    AND er.`cancelled_at` IS NULL 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      ep.*
    FROM
      `expense_report_payment` ep 
      JOIN `payments` p 
        ON p.`id` = ep.`payment_id`
    WHERE p.`received_at` IS NOT NULL
    AND p.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    AND p.`cancelled_at` IS NULL
    ) AS erp 
    ON erp.expense_report_id = er.`id` 
WHERE ex.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

`LEFT JOIN` tables. Generally, you also should move `WHERE` conditions on right tables of joins to `LEFT JOIN`s  `ON` clause. Try

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(SUM(ex.`amount`), 0) AS total_expenses,
  IFNULL(SUM(erp.`payment`), 0) AS total_payment 
FROM
  `expenses` ex 
  LEFT JOIN `expense_reports` er 
    ON er.`id` = ex.`expense_report_id` 
      AND er.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
      AND er.`rejected_at` IS NULL 
      AND er.`cancelled_at` IS NULL    
  LEFT JOIN `expense_report_payment` erp 
    ON erp.`expense_report_id` = er.`id` 
  LEFT JOIN `payments` p 
    ON p.`id` = erp.`payment_id` 
    AND p.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
    AND p.`cancelled_at` IS NULL 
    AND p.`received_at` IS NOT NULL 
WHERE ex.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried your suggestion but it still shows the payment even if the payment is not received yet. That is why I JOINED the 'payments' table with the 'expense_report_payment' table in the first place.